# Laravel PHP, getting clicked link class

Tags: php, class, laravel

I have a html5 table which is dynamically made from database items and it contains links, e.g. delete icon, which is in link tags `<a href="xxxx" class="yyyy"></a>`. I want to be able to click the delete icon and know, which item I want to delete. I have set class of the link the same as the relevant database items ID, but I cant read the class from the controller, after I click the link. Is there a method of doing that in PHP Laravel? Or maybe you could suggest a way better way to accomplish that? This seems a way off tactic for this.

Answer (score 1):

If each row on the table represents a row on database, so your link could contain the id from database.
For example, a user table.

```
Row 1 => Link /users/delete/1 
Row 2 => Link /users/delete/2 
Row 3 => Link /users/delete/3
```

By doing it this way, you can know for sure which one is called.
On your routes file, if you are not using `Route::resource()`, you should have something like this:

```
Route::get('users/delete/{id}', 'UsersController@destroy');
```

And in your `destroy` method:

```
public function destroy($id) 
{
    // your logic here
}
```

Comment: Ouh, I think I have formulated the question a little big wrong. I am getting the data from DB in the controller, then creating view with the red data, and then making a table from those.
I found a solution, not the best one, but it will work.
I just put the table inside a  form, and instead of the links and images, I used radio buttons, with the value of the ID. Then I will just read the value from the checked radio button with Input::get :)

Answer (score 0):

Format your **links** as:
If for example you are listing all items using foreach:

```
@foreach( $items as $item )
<a href="{{URL::to('/item/delete/'.$item->id}}">{{$item->name}}</a>
@endforeach
```

Inside **routes.php**

```
Route::get('item/delete/{id}', 'ItemsController@deleteItem');
```

inside **ItemsController.php** define the following function

```
public function deleteItem($id) {
  $item = Item::get($id);
  if( !$item ) App::abort(404);

  $item->delete();
  return Redirect::to('/');
}
```

and I am assuming you have your model in Item.php

```
class Item extends Eloquent {
  protected $table = 'items';
}
```

and your items table has id and name columns

Comment: Hi, thanks for suggestion, I will use it.
But I am getting a problem with the route file. It gets it right in the link section of the browser (item/delete/correctId), but trows an error: `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145:`
I believe, that in the route file, it doesn't get the {id} as expected

Comment: Edit you question to include the whole of `routes.php` or at least the section that is causing the problem.